# Could not match type with Maybe b0

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor

Hello i am encountering the following problem:
I have defined a typeclass:

**Typeclass**

```
class TextEncode  a where
        toText::a->Text
        fromText::Text->a
```

And i want to parse a `TCPFile`:

```
data TCPFile=Rfile (Maybe Readme) | Dfile  Samples | Empty
```

I will not show the `Samples` and `Readme` types because they do not matter in this case.I am trying to use the `fromText` method to get a `TCPFile`.

**Types**

```
data FileData=FileData{ header::Header,rawContent::Text}

data Header=Header { ftype::Char}
```

The `FileData` is used to store the `Header` of the file and the content that will get parsed:

I am using a `Functor` defined by me for chaining operations:

```
(>>?)::Maybe a->(a->Maybe b)->Maybe b
    (Just t) >>? f=f t
    Nothing >>? _=Nothing
```

**Code**

```
instance TextEncode TCPFile where
        fromText txt = readHeader txt >>? (\h -> Just (FileData h txt)) >>? makeFile


    readHeader::Text->Maybe Header
    readHeader txt=case Data.Text.head txt of 
        'r' ->Just (Header{ ftype='r'})
        'd' ->Just (Header {ftype ='d'})
        _  ->Nothing



    makeFile::FileData->TCPFile
    makeFile fd= case ftype.header $ fd of
            'r'->Rfile (Just (fromText . rawContent $ fd))
            'd'->Dfile (fromText . rawContent $ fd)
            _  ->Empty
```

I keep getting this error in `makeFile` method and i do not understand why.What i put inside `makeFile` is a `Maybe FileData`,that is unwrapped via `>>?`.So i provide a good input parameter and i output a `TCPFile` which matches the `TextEncode` `typeclass`.What is wrong here?

**Error**

```
  TCPFile.hs:59:24: error:
        * Couldn't match expected type `TCPFile'
                      with actual type `Maybe b0'
        * In the expression:
            readHeader txt >>? (\ h -> Just (FileData h txt)) >>? makeFile
          In an equation for `fromText':
              fromText txt
                = readHeader txt >>? (\ h -> Just (FileData h txt)) >>? makeFile
          In the instance declaration for `TextEncode TCPFile'
       |
    59 |         fromText txt = readHeader txt >>? (\h -> Just (FileData h txt)) >>? makeFile

       |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

^^^
```

Comment: The `>>?` operator wants a function `(a -> Maybe b)` as second parameter, but its type declaration is `FileData -> TCPFile`, where the return value isn't wrapped in a maybe

Comment: Oh damn..you are right...I need to exit the `>>?` chain somehow

Comment: Not sure what you mean by exiting the `>>?` chain, but I'd say you need to change the type of `makeFile` to `FileData -> Maybe TCPFile`. I think you'll stumble upon other problems after that, but it's a first step

Comment: Well my problem is that if i take your advice i still have to `unwrap` from the `Maybe TCPFile` to `TCPFile` to match the `fromText` signature, outside the `makeFile`

Comment: That's true. If it's possible, I'd change the signature of `fromText` to `Text -> Maybe a`. It makes sense because fromText is essentially a parser which is supposed to be able to fail (`Nothing` usually represents a failed operation).

Comment: Yes but then my `Empty` data constructor  from `TCPFile` type constructor would be useless right? I can remove that as well.I provided it for the case if the parser fails , wanting to not use `Maybe`

Comment: I think I'd remove it. It's better to make it clear in the `fromText` type declaration that it can fail, instead of relying that the type given to the instance that implements `TextEncode` (in this case `TCPFile`) has a constructor that represents failing.